# How to say a DropDownChoice to update it list of choices?

Tags: java, ajax, drop-down-menu, wicket

I have 3 DropDownChoice COuntry>State>Cities and its updating ok with Ajax on onchage method with ajax behaivor.

What about if I want to set 3 values via JAVA and not AJAX? I have the selected values mapped to a property model for each one. Those values are private members in the class:

```
private CountrySel;
private StateSel;
private CitySel;
```

If in the constructor I set those 3 values my self via java, only the country get selected, others ddc dont load data neither. What method should I call or override for get the ddc calling getModel again via JAVA?

Ill post the code. I code this with the example here: http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/ajax/choice.

```
package pqlrd.ui;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.LinkedList;

import org.apache.wicket.ajax.form.AjaxFormChoiceComponentUpdatingBehavior;
import org.apache.wicket.ajax.form.AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior;
import org.apache.wicket.ajax.form.OnChangeAjaxBehavior;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.basic.Label;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.DropDownChoice;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.TextField;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.Panel;
import org.apache.wicket.model.AbstractReadOnlyModel;
import org.apache.wicket.model.IModel;
import org.apache.wicket.model.LoadableDetachableModel;
import org.apache.wicket.model.Model;
import org.apache.wicket.model.PropertyModel;
import org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxRequestTarget;

import com.sun.mail.iap.Response;
import com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.operations.Mod;

import pqlrd.domain.Ciudad;
import pqlrd.domain.Estado;
import pqlrd.domain.Pais;
import pqlrd.domain.Sector;

public class PanelDireccion extends Panel {


private TextField tbCalle ;
private TextField tbNumeroC ;
private TextField tbApartamento;
private TextField tbNumeroA ;
private DropDownChoice cmbSector;
private DropDownChoice cmbCiudad;
private DropDownChoice cmbEstado;

private Ciudad cSel;
private Estado pSel;
private Sector sSel;
private Pais paisRD;


public Pais getPaisRD() {
    return paisRD;
}

public void setPaisRD(Pais paisRD) {
    this.paisRD = paisRD;
}

public TextField getTbCalle() {
    return tbCalle;
}

public void setTbCalle(TextField tbCalle) {
    this.tbCalle = tbCalle;
}

public TextField getTbNumeroC() {
    return tbNumeroC;
}

public void setTbNumeroC(TextField tbNumeroC) {
    this.tbNumeroC = tbNumeroC;
}

public TextField getTbApartamento() {
    return tbApartamento;
}

public void setTbApartamento(TextField tbApartamento) {
    this.tbApartamento = tbApartamento;
}

public TextField getTbNumeroA() {
    return tbNumeroA;
}

public void setTbNumeroA(TextField tbNumeroA) {
    this.tbNumeroA = tbNumeroA;
}

public DropDownChoice getCmbSector() {
    return cmbSector;
}

public void setCmbSector(DropDownChoice cmbSector) {
    this.cmbSector = cmbSector;
}

public DropDownChoice getCmbCiudad() {
    return cmbCiudad;
}

public void setCmbCiudad(DropDownChoice cmbCiudad) {
    this.cmbCiudad = cmbCiudad;
}

public DropDownChoice getCmbEstado() {
    return cmbEstado;
}

public void setCmbEstado(DropDownChoice cmbEstado) {
    this.cmbEstado = cmbEstado;
}

public Sector getsSel() {
    return sSel;
}

public void setsSel(Sector sSel) {
    this.sSel = sSel;
}

public List<Estado> getProvincias() {
    return provincias;
}

public void setProvincias(List<Estado> provincias) {
    this.provincias = provincias;
}

public HashMap<Estado, List<Ciudad>> getMunicipios() {
    return municipios;
}

public void setMunicipios(HashMap<Estado, List<Ciudad>> municipios) {
    this.municipios = municipios;
}

public HashMap<Ciudad, List<Sector>> getSectores() {
    return sectores;
}

public void setSectores(HashMap<Ciudad, List<Sector>> sectores) {
    this.sectores = sectores;
}

public Ciudad getcSel() {
    return cSel;
}

public void setcSel(Ciudad cSel) {
    this.cSel = cSel;
}

public Estado getpSel() {
    return pSel;
}

public void setpSel(Estado pSel) {
    this.pSel = pSel;
}

private List<Estado> provincias;
private HashMap<Estado, List<Ciudad>> municipios;
private HashMap<Ciudad, List<Sector>> sectores;


public PanelDireccion(String id) {
    super(id);






    IModel<List<Estado>> mProvincia = new AbstractReadOnlyModel<List<Estado>>(){
        @Override
        public List<Estado> getObject() {
            return  provincias;

        }
    };


    IModel<List<Ciudad>> mMunicipio = new AbstractReadOnlyModel<List<Ciudad>>(){

        @Override
        public List<Ciudad> getObject() {

            return (List<Ciudad>) ((municipios.get(pSel) == null)? Collections.emptyList() :  municipios.get(pSel));

        }
    };

    IModel<List<Sector>> mSector = new AbstractReadOnlyModel<List<Sector>>() {


        @Override
        public List<Sector> getObject() {


            return (List<Sector>) ((sectores.get(cSel)==null) ? Collections.emptyList() : sectores.get(cSel)); 

        }
    }; 



    add(tbCalle= (TextField) new TextField("tbCalle", new Model<String>() ));
    add(tbNumeroC = (TextField) new TextField("tbNumeroC", new Model<String>() )) ;

    add(tbApartamento = (TextField) new TextField("tbApartamento", new Model<String>() )) ;
    add(tbNumeroA = new TextField("tbNumeroA", new Model<String>() ) );

    add(cmbSector = new DropDownChoice("cmbSector", new PropertyModel<Sector>(this, "sSel"), mSector ));
    add(cmbEstado=new DropDownChoice("cmbEstado",new PropertyModel<Estado>(this, "pSel") ,mProvincia)); 
    add(cmbCiudad=new DropDownChoice("cmbCiudad", new PropertyModel<Ciudad>(this, "cSel") ,mMunicipio));

    cmbCiudad.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    cmbSector.setOutputMarkupId(true);


    //cmbCiudad.setOutputMarkupId(true);


    //Pais que voy a traer en este caso solo es RD.
     paisRD = new Pais();

    try{

     paisRD = (Pais) paisRD.getPaisById(70);

    }
    catch (Exception e) {



    }


    //La lista de provincias;
    provincias =  paisRD.getEstados();

     municipios = new HashMap<Estado, List<Ciudad>>();
     sectores = new HashMap<Ciudad, List<Sector>>();

    //Llenar los municipios de cada provincia
    for( Estado e : provincias)
    {

         municipios.put(e, e.getCiudades());

         for(Ciudad c: e.getCiudades())
             sectores.put(c, c.getSectores());

    }

    cmbEstado.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onchange") {

        @Override
        protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            target.add(cmbCiudad);

        }
    });


    cmbCiudad.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onchange") {

        @Override
        protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            target.add(cmbSector);

        }
    });



    }

}
```

Sorry for the language. What I want to do is keep the ajax behaivor, but let say I query an Direccion(Address) obect from database I want to select myself the values of the combobox, but is not possible because the two dependant ddc havent a model. Please help.

Comment: Hi can you write down your code here?

Comment: Its look like a McGyver Problem.

Answer (score 3):

See http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/ajax/choice just to get the idea how to do that task. To avoid Ajax see org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.DropDownChoice#wantOnSelectionChangedNotifications() javadoc.

Comment: I read the DDC Javadoc and it looks that I have to override the onSelectionChanged method. What do you think?